# Get icon from single png image

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I have seen this so many times until now, but I never used myself. Can somebody explain how you can get specific icon picture from this single png image, for example the icons i selected with red ... using css

[image]

Comment: It is called css sprite. to understand this, you need to be aware of the width and height of each icon.

Comment: @Mr_Green I kinda tought the same when there are different size icons ..

Comment: adding to the below solutions, also take help of the designer who created this image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is called [CSS sprites](https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20sprite&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). It is used to cut down the http requests. Basically all icons are placed on a single canvas and are used as `background-image` property and later they are mapped using CSS `background-position` property, so for example

```
.icon1 {
   background-image: url('YOUR_URL_HERE');
   background-position: 10px 10px; /* X and Y */
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T2EtY/)

So inshort just define a fix height/width to your element, and than map the canvas using `background-position` property. Hence, if you have 100 small icon images on a page, it will make 100 requests to the server, thus to increase the performance, CSS Sprites are used.

Comment: One question: how do you get the background-position? I mean you try it until you get the right picture? Is there a technique or a tool that does that?

Comment: @DavidDury Either manually or you will get tons of [sprite generators](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprite+generator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 5):

1. Set a fixed (in pixels) `height` and `width` on an element
2. Set the image as the `background-image`
3. Adjust `background-position` so the part of the image you want to be visible is in view

Answer (score 1):

Using background shorthand for the positioning of image.

```
div {
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUhg1.png) -82px -104px;
    width:27px;
    height:27px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2EtY/1/