# Best way to toggle image's background on hover?

Tags: css, hover, transparency, css-sprites

I'm wondering which way would be the best.
I have some semi-transparent anchor images which change fully transparent background to half-transparent red background on hover:
[image] ->
[image]

The employer provided me with red-background versions for each image, but of course I don't want to use them because it would be a total bandwidth waste. Instead I want to
option 1 : toggle background image on hover with 1 universal image:
[image]
option 2: use CSS3, but I'm not sure if it's possible

btw. I've read many good opinions about CSS sprites, is it a good idea to convert whole image positioning on website to that in sprite fashion? or is it only recommended for certain image type, like anchors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprites is a good way to go when you have fragmented images all over your website, like say for example icons like email, phone, services etc, the more images you have, the more `http` request it creates, thus making your website ineffecient. Also, using CSS Sprites, the buttons won't create a glitch when you hover them, yea, obviously only the first time user may experience a glitch but it will create a bad impression in general which you can come over by using CSS Sprites as you will have to just change the `background-position` of the image.

Coming to the buttons, if you want you can simply use CSS sprites, place both the button state over a single canvas, and use them using `background-image` property and later switch them using `background-position` property on hover.

On the other hand, you can also use CSS3 if the effect you want is possible. By looking at the images, I don't think even CSS3 is required. If these are not the real buttons, and the real buttons are extra fancy, CSS Sprites would be a good way to go for as IE will spoil your CSS3 buttons.

As far as the transparency goes, you can use `rgba()` where `a` stands for opacity. You can also beautify them using CSS Transitions for a smoother hover effects.

You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180761/get-icon-from-single-png-image/18180792#18180792) if you want a quick overview of what CSS Sprite is and how to use them.

Comment: @MrAlien big thanks for the advise with `rgba()`! I've just wanted to post a fiddle with a problem, but I've made it work: http://jsfiddle.net/nv32Z/2/ it needs some design corrections, though. anyway I think I got the general idea.

Comment: btw, just a lil correction, `a` in `rgba` stands for `alpha` ;)